# Drupal 7 views_embed_view and templates

Tags: php, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-templates

In Drupal 7

- created a block view (called *super_gallery*) of *grid* format
- added a template specialization `views-view-grid--super-gallery--block.tpl.php`
- cleared theme registry
- cleared all caches

Using preview in view editor I can see output modified by the template. **GOOD**

Using `<?php print views_embed_view("super_gallery", "default", $gallery_arguments); ?>`
inside another template to show *super_gallery* view, it shows output without changes. **BAD**

**How can I use templates with `views_embed_view`?**

**EDIT 1**
Tried also with:

```
$view = views_get_view("super_gallery");
print $view->preview("default", $gallery_arguments);
```

and

```
$view = views_get_view("super_gallery");
print $view->execute_display("default", $gallery_arguments);
```

Nothing changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
print views_embed_view("super_gallery", "block", $gallery_arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this module

http://drupal.org/project/embed_views

OR Have a look at the following comment

http://drupal.org/node/1138866#comment-4845070

Comment: Installed, bu I don't understand how this module can help me. I'm already using views_embed_view, and it embeds the view, even without *embed_views* installed. But it doesn't use the template *views-view-grid--super-gallery--block.tpl.php*

Comment: @AlessandroPezzato How did you solve the issue eventually or was it a Views bug that was fixed? Because currently I am not experiencing this problem.